# C# Windows Form App on top

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm wondering if is posible for a Windows Form program to cover the pointer.

I want to have an animation as a part of a C# WinForm app and be on top of everything, even the pointer, is it possible and if it is, what to do?

p.s. this question extends to the desktop popup menu too.

Comment: Did you tried _anything_? Read [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: Why must it cover the cursor?

Answer (score 1):

You can hide the cursor while the animation is running, then show it again after it has finished.

```
cursor.Hide();
```